# Why does my float right and left not working

Tags: html, jquery, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-W2TTYM16Z1"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-W2TTYM16Z1');
  </script>

  <!-- Tags ads proppeller anuncio falta verificar-->
  <meta name='propeller' content='8501c5d1862d685dc200c4af5e2450fc' />
  <!-- Fim ads proppeller anuncio -->

  <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="icon" href="tab.png">


  <title>StopWatch</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .container {
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: black;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 50% 100px;
    }
    
    .btn {
      margin: 0px 2%;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      #butoes {
        margin-top: 40%;
      }
    }
    
    .ts {
      border-radius: 25px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    
    a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .gog {
      position: absolute;
      top: -50px;
      right: -5000000px;
    }
    
    #logoBanner {
      position: fixed;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    #logo {
      margin-left: 20px;
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="logoBanner" style="border:1px solid;">
    <a href="https://stopwatch.ml/"><img id="logo" src="logo2.png"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <div class=" float-right  float-md-none float-sm-none justify-content-center" style="border:solid 1px;width: 48%;margin-top: 15%;padding-left: 8%;   text-align: center;">
      <div style="font-size: 30px;background-color: black;border-radius: 10px;color: white;">StopWatch Premium</div>
      <div style="font-size: 20px;" class="mt-3">No Ads</div>
      <div style="font-size: 20px;" class="mt-3">Time Log</div>
      <div style="font-size: 20px;" class="mt-3">Single Payment</div>

    </div>
    <div class="float-left" style="width: 20%; margin-top: 12%;font-size: 20px;border:1px solid;">
      <form style="margin-left: 100px; " action="verifica_regist.php" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-4">
          Register:
        </div>
        <?php

                    echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects:' );</script>";
                    if(isset($_SESSION['emailExistente'])):
                    ?>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="width: 94%">
            <p>ERRO: Email already registed.</p>
          </div>
          <?php
                    endif;
                    ?>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
              <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" style="width: 90%;" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
              <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text" style="font-size: 15px;">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
              <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 90%;" id="exampleInputPassword1">
            </div>
            <button style="margin: 0px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


  <footer class="fixed-bottom clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <span class="ts float-left"><a href="ut.html" class="site" > Use Terms</a></span>
      <span class="ts float-right"><a href="pp.html" class="site" > Privacy Policy</a></span>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
  <!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Hi i'm doing a site and i'm trying to do a register page.
However, the float property is not working.
I want the form register on the right and the information on the left.
The logo "stopwatch" is struggling i dont know why. Sometimes it appears on the top, where it is supposed to be.
here is the code :

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-W2TTYM16Z1"></script>
    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-W2TTYM16Z1');
    </script>

    <!-- Tags ads proppeller anuncio falta verificar-->
    <meta name='propeller' content='8501c5d1862d685dc200c4af5e2450fc' />
    <!-- Fim ads proppeller anuncio -->

    <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="icon" href="tab.png">


    <title>StopWatch</title>
    <style type="text/css">

      html,body{
        height: 100%;
        font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
      }
      .container{
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: black;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 50% 100px;
      }
 
      .btn{
        margin: 0px 2%;
        background-color: black;

      }



        .ts{
          border-radius: 25px;
          padding:  10px;
          margin-bottom:  10px;
          margin-left:  10px;
          margin-right:   10px;
          color:  white;
          background-color: black;
          font-size:15px;
        }

a { color: inherit ;text-decoration:  none; } 
a:hover { color: inherit;text-decoration:  none; } 
  .gog{
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: -5000000px;
    }
    #logoBanner{
      z-index: 1;
      position: fixed;
      height: 50px;
    }
    #logo{
      margin-left: 20px;
      width: 200px;
    }


    </style>
  </head>
  <body >


         <div id="logoBanner" style="border:1px solid;" >
           <a  href="https://stopwatch.ml/"><img id="logo" src="logo2.png"></a>
         </div>

    <div class="clearfix" >
      <div   class=" float-right  float-md-none float-sm-none justify-content-center" style="border:solid 1px;width: 48%;margin-top: 15%;padding-left: 8%;   text-align: center;">
        <div style="font-size: 30px;background-color: black;border-radius: 10px;color: white;" >StopWatch Premium</div>
        <div style="font-size: 20px;"class="mt-3">No Ads</div>
        <div style="font-size: 20px;"class="mt-3">Time Log</div>
        <div style="font-size: 20px;"class="mt-3">Single Payment</div>

      </div>
      <div   class="float-left" style="width: 20%; margin-top: 12%;font-size: 20px;border:1px solid;">
        <form style="margin-left: 100px; " action="verifica_regist.php" method="POST">
          <div class="mb-4">
            Register:
          </div>
                    <?php

                    echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects:' );</script>";
                    if(isset($_SESSION['emailExistente'])):
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="width: 94%">
                      <p>ERRO: Email already registed.</p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    ?>
        <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" style="width: 90%;" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text" style="font-size: 15px;">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input  name="password" type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 90%;" id="exampleInputPassword1">
        </div>
        <button style="margin: 0px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div> 

  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


      <footer class="fixed-bottom clearfix">
          <div class="clearfix"  >
            <span class="ts float-left"><a href="ut.html" class="site" > Use Terms</a></span> 
              <span class="ts float-right"  ><a href="pp.html" class="site" > Privacy Policy</a></span> 
          </div>  
      </footer>
    <!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
    <!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</script>

  </body>
</html> ```
````

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example with a snippet ? Here is a link on how to implement it in your post. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Comment: it didn't work i dont know why but here is the problem [printscreen](https://prnt.sc/10aiipt)
The logo doesnt appear on top , and the float right and left isn't working. I also used clearfix.

Answer (score 0):

You had some weird `float-sm-none` and `float-md-none` properties which I removed and furthermore I added to both columns a `float-left` and a `float-right` respectively, the first would go the left and the right would come up to the right side.

```css
  html,body{
        height: 100%;
        font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
      }
      .container{
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: black;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 50% 100px;
      }
 
      .btn{
        margin: 0px 2%;
        background-color: black;

      }



        .ts{
          border-radius: 25px;
          padding:  10px;
          margin-bottom:  10px;
          margin-left:  10px;
          margin-right:   10px;
          color:  white;
          background-color: black;
          font-size:15px;
        }

a { color: inherit ;text-decoration:  none; } 
a:hover { color: inherit;text-decoration:  none; } 
  .gog{
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: -5000000px;
    }
    #logoBanner{
      z-index: 1;
      position: fixed;
      height: 50px;
    }
    #logo{
      margin-left: 20px;
      width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-W2TTYM16Z1"></script>
    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-W2TTYM16Z1');
    </script>

    <!-- Tags ads proppeller anuncio falta verificar-->
    <meta name='propeller' content='8501c5d1862d685dc200c4af5e2450fc' />
    <!-- Fim ads proppeller anuncio -->

    <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="icon" href="tab.png">


    <title>StopWatch</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    

    </style>
  </head>
  <body >


         <div id="logoBanner" style="border:1px solid;" >
           <a  href="https://stopwatch.ml/"><img id="logo" src="logo2.png"></a>
         </div>

    <div class="clearfix" >
      <div class="float-left justify-content-center" style="border:solid 1px;width: 46%;margin-right: 3%;margin-top: 15%;padding-left: 8%;   text-align: center;">
        <div style="font-size: 30px;background-color: black;border-radius: 10px;color: white;" >StopWatch Premium</div>
        <div style="font-size: 20px;"class="mt-3">No Ads</div>
        <div style="font-size: 20px;"class="mt-3">Time Log</div>
        <div style="font-size: 20px;"class="mt-3">Single Payment</div>

      </div>
      <div class="float-right" style="width: 45%; margin-top: 12%;font-size: 20px;border:1px solid;">
        <form style="margin-left: 100px; " action="verifica_regist.php" method="POST">
          <div class="mb-4">
            Register:
          </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="width: 94%">
                      <p>ERRO: Email already registed.</p>
                    </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" style="width: 90%;" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text" style="font-size: 15px;">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input  name="password" type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 90%;" id="exampleInputPassword1">
        </div>
        <button style="margin: 0px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div> 

  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


      <footer class="fixed-bottom clearfix">
          <div class="clearfix"  >
            <span class="ts float-left"><a href="ut.html" class="site" > Use Terms</a></span> 
              <span class="ts float-right"  ><a href="pp.html" class="site" > Privacy Policy</a></span> 
          </div>  
      </footer>
    <!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
    <!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I think that piece of code can give you a glimpse on how to tackle your problem. I would personally choose to do it with Bootstrap.